# How to make a good constructor for the wxpython interface?

Tags: wxpython

with wxpython I had created a graphical interface but it turns out that when I closed the application I got an error in the console and wanted to know what I had done wrong.
version that I use

- wxpython 4.0.4
- python 3.5 "x64"

**--  code    --**

```
import wx
import wx.xrc
import wx.aui
import gettext
_ = gettext.gettext
## Class MyFrame1
class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__( self, parent, *args, **kwds ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 634,367 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE )

        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
        self.m_mgr = wx.aui.AuiManager()
        self.m_mgr.SetManagedWindow( self )

        self.m_mgr.SetFlags(wx.aui.AUI_MGR_ALLOW_ACTIVE_PANE|
        wx.aui.AUI_MGR_DEFAULT|wx.aui.AUI_MGR_LIVE_RESIZE)

        self.m_auinotebook1 = wx.aui.AuiNotebook( self, wx.ID_ANY,wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 320,-1 ), wx.aui.AUI_NB_DEFAULT_STYLE )
        self.m_mgr.AddPane( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.aui.AuiPaneInfo() .Left() .PinButton( True ).Dock().Resizable().FloatingSize( wx.DefaultSize ) )

        self.m_panel2 = wx.Panel( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.ID_ANY,wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_auinotebook1.AddPage( self.m_panel2, _(u"Inicio"), False,wx.NullBitmap )

        self.m_statusBar1 = self.CreateStatusBar( 1, wx.STB_SIZEGRIP, wx.ID_ANY )
        self.m_menubar1 = wx.MenuBar( 0 )
        self.m_menu1 = wx.Menu()
        self.m_menuItem1 = wx.MenuItem( self.m_menu1, wx.ID_ANY, _(u"Guardar"), wx.EmptyString, wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.m_menu1.Append( self.m_menuItem1 )

        self.m_menu1.AppendSeparator()

        self.m_menuItem2 = wx.MenuItem( self.m_menu1, wx.ID_ANY, _(u"Salir"), wx.EmptyString, wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.m_menu1.Append( self.m_menuItem2 )

        self.m_menubar1.Append( self.m_menu1, _(u"Inicio") )

        self.SetMenuBar( self.m_menubar1 )

        self.m_mgr.Update()
        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_MENU, self.Save, id = self.m_menuItem1.GetId() )
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_MENU, self.Exit, id = self.m_menuItem2.GetId() )

    def __del__( self ):
        self.m_mgr.UnInit()

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def Save( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def Exit( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame = MyFrame1(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**_________error_______**

the error originates the MainLoop (), but I do not know what I'm failing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\DennisM\Documents\Archivos de Outlook\proyecto.py", line 76, 
in <module>
app.MainLoop()
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 2166, in MainLoop
rv = wx.PyApp.MainLoop(self)
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "GetEventHandler() == this" failed 
at ..\..\src\common\wincmn.cpp(478) in wxWindowBase::~wxWindowBase(): any 
pushed event handlers must have been removed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't used `self.Destroy()` in `Exit` and you have written your own `__del__` method for the `AuiManager's` `UnInit`.
Add in a `Bind` to the window's `EVT_CLOSE` and you should have a program that behaves itself.
i.e.

```
import wx
import wx.xrc
import wx.aui
import gettext
_ = gettext.gettext
## Class MyFrame1
class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__( self, parent, *args, **kwds ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 634,367 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE )
        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
        self.m_mgr = wx.aui.AuiManager()
        self.m_mgr.SetManagedWindow( self )

        self.m_mgr.SetFlags(wx.aui.AUI_MGR_ALLOW_ACTIVE_PANE|
        wx.aui.AUI_MGR_DEFAULT|wx.aui.AUI_MGR_LIVE_RESIZE)

        self.m_auinotebook1 = wx.aui.AuiNotebook( self, wx.ID_ANY,wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 320,-1 ), wx.aui.AUI_NB_DEFAULT_STYLE )
        self.m_mgr.AddPane( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.aui.AuiPaneInfo() .Left() .PinButton( True ).Dock().Resizable().FloatingSize( wx.DefaultSize ) )

        self.m_panel2 = wx.Panel( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.ID_ANY,wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_auinotebook1.AddPage( self.m_panel2, _(u"Inicio"), False,wx.NullBitmap )

        self.m_statusBar1 = self.CreateStatusBar( 1, wx.STB_SIZEGRIP, wx.ID_ANY )
        self.m_menubar1 = wx.MenuBar( 0 )
        self.m_menu1 = wx.Menu()
        self.m_menuItem1 = wx.MenuItem( self.m_menu1, wx.ID_ANY, _(u"Guardar"), wx.EmptyString, wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.m_menu1.Append( self.m_menuItem1 )

        self.m_menu1.AppendSeparator()

        self.m_menuItem2 = wx.MenuItem( self.m_menu1, wx.ID_ANY, _(u"Salir"), wx.EmptyString, wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.m_menu1.Append( self.m_menuItem2 )

        self.m_menubar1.Append( self.m_menu1, _(u"Inicio") )

        self.SetMenuBar( self.m_menubar1 )

        self.m_mgr.Update()
        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_MENU, self.Save, id = self.m_menuItem1.GetId() )
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_MENU, self.Exit, id = self.m_menuItem2.GetId() )
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.Exit)

    #def __del__( self ):
    #    self.m_mgr.UnInit()

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def Save( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def Exit( self, event ):
        self.m_mgr.UnInit()
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame = MyFrame1(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for your response and it really works. **Rolf of Saxony**